# JavaScript not executing with form validation

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am relatively new to web development and I'm trying to do some form validation with javascript but my javascript block is not executing and I really don't know why. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" href = "formato.css" />
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function validate(){
            var x = document.forms[LoginInformation][username].value;
            var y = document.forms[LoginInformation][password].value;
            if(document.LoginInformation){
                alert("Enter a username");
                return false;
            }
            if(y===null || x ===""){
                alert("Enter a password");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id = "login">

        <form method = "post" name = "LoginInformation" onsubmit = "return (validate());" action="./TestLogin">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Informaci&oacute;n de Login</legend>
                <label>Usuario:<br />
                <input type="text" name="username" size ="15"/></label><br /> 
                <label>Contrase&ntilde;a:<br />
                <input type="password" name="password" size ="15"/></label><br />
                <label><br /><input type = "submit" name = "login" value = "Login"/></label><br />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: the very first thing to try when debugging JavaScript is to have your browser's developer console open.  Hit F12 in Chrome or Firefox to pop it up, then reload your page and perform whatever actions needed to trigger your JavaScript, and see what happens.

Comment: @orzechowskid Sorry, but what am I supposed to see? (or not to see)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
    function validate(){
        var x = document.getElementbyID("username");
        var y = document.getElementbyID("password");
        if(x==""){
            alert("Enter a username");
            return false;
        }
        if(y==null || x ==""){
            alert("Enter a password");
            return false;
        }
     }
   </script>
```

and then all you code in between

```
<form method="post" name="LoginInformation" action="./TestLogin">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Informaci&oacute;n de Login</legend>
            <label>Usuario:<br />
            <input type="text" id="username" size ="15"/></label><br /> 
            <label>Contrase&ntilde;a:<br />
            <input type="password" id="password" size ="15"/></label><br />
            <label><br /><input type ="submit" name ="login" value = "Login" onClick="validate()"/></label><br />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks it worked. What is the difference between onClick and onsubmit?

Comment: @Darwin57721 By the way what is action="./TestLogin in your form?

Comment: oh, that is my servlet to test that the login information is being sent correctly to the database

Comment: ONClick will work for that specific control event, on submit is more complicated.Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/ it may help.

Comment: @Darwin57721 It is a common courtesy here to accept the answer when it was what you needed

Answer (score 1):

Please pass the form id and control id as string as mentioned below

`var x = document.forms["LoginInformation"]["username"].value;
var y = document.forms["LoginInformation"]["password"].value;`

Answer (score 0):

in your `validate` function you need to have `LoginInformation`, `username`, and `password` enclosed in quotation marks.  If it's not, your JavaScript interpreter will consider them as regular ol' JavaScript variables, which they're not.